# Is there any way to open multiple emails using mailto: tag?

Tags: php

I am using `mailto:` links to send email to multiple people, but I have PHP code which fetches emails from the database.  I am using Thunderbird, which limits emails addresses to 60.

How can I write PHP code to send more than 60 emails?

Is it possible to write code to open more than one email (with 50 emails each) when the link is clicked?

Comment: Are you wanting to actually send the email using PHP, or are you trying to open up a user's mail client and pre-populate it with more than 60 addresses?

Comment: Do you want to open one email with 60 addresses, or 60 emails with one address each?

Answer (score 2):

Yes use the comma.

```
<a href="mailto:john.doe@gmail.com,lucy.jane@gmail.com">Email Staff</a>
```

Some clients prefer the < or >

```
<a href="mailto:<john.doe@gmail.com>,<lucy.jane@gmail.com>">Email Staff</a>
```

As this would be tricky, best use this universal fix:

```
<a href='mailto: "John Smith" <john.doe@gmail.com>, "Lucy Jane" <lucy.jane@gmail.com>'>Email Staff</a>
```

Note the ' and now "

For the PHP solution, just get an Array from your Database and send using mail() with the Array.

Comment: I have not tested it. But a simple Array for your 60 email etc: http://snipplr.com/view/7798/